# Monitor applications with zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, application

How to monitor applications(mysql, tomcat, ....) with zabbix?

Please need step by step guide

Comment: Too generic; also, do not post responses to your own question.  Either edit your question, or use the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Zabbix is probably the best documented monitoring tool what I have ever seen.

http://www.zabbix.com/documentation.php

Please read the documentation and ask specific questions. If you don't want to dive deep into zabbix hire somebody who does.